# Samba35 configuration on FreeBSD 8.1 RELEASE

Tags: samba, freebsd, server-message-block, smb-conf

I'm currently trying to create a Samba share on a lightweight home network, and I'm having a bit of trouble configuring Samba 3.5.6 compiled from the ports tree.

What I'm looking for is pretty basic. I just want a share with no limits, that anyone can have access to on my home network. More specifically, I do not and will not ever need printing.

`/usr/local/etc/smb.conf` looks like this:

```
#======================= Global Settings =====================================
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = Server
   security = user
;   netbios name = Server
   hosts allow = 192.168.1. 127.
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 50
   interfaces = 192.168.1.254/24 192.168.1.253/24
   wins support = yes
   guest account = ftp

#============================ Share Definitions ==============================
[drop]
   comment = Server Drop
   path = /usr/drop/
   public = yes
   writeable = yes
   printable = no
;   admin users = User
   browseable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   hide dot files = yes
```

And when I run `testparm` I get the following output:

```
$ testparm
Load smb config files from /usr/local/etc/smb.conf
max_open_files: sysctl_max (11095) below minimum Windows limit (16384)
rlimit_max: rlimit_max (11095) below minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[drop]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

[global]
        server string = Server
        interfaces = 192.168.1.254/24, 192.168.1.253/24
        guest account = ftp
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 50
        wins support = Yes
        hosts allow = 192.168.1., 127.

[drop]
        comment = Server Drop
        path = /usr/drop/
        read only = No
        guest ok = Yes
```

However, when I try to test this connection locally with `smbclient \\\\localhost\\drop\\` I get the following output:

```
$ smbclient \\\\localhost\\drop\\
Enter User's password:
Connection to localhost failed (Error NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER)
```

I have also come across a similar issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034380/why-smb-returns-nt-status-invalid-parameter-how-to-fix-smbclient, but that's amazingly vague and doesn't come with a solution.

Any advice on what to fix?

EDIT: It appears the problem may go deeper than this. Despite the line `samba_enable="YES"` in `/etc/rc.conf`, and despite restarting samba a few times after bootup, running `ps -ax | grep mbd` to see what's running gives me:

```
$ ps -aux | grep mdb
root   1802  0.0  0.1  7044  1348   0  R+    9:41PM   0:00.00 grep mdb
```

Implying that Samba isn't even running, despite all my....

```
$ /usr/local/etc/rc.d/samba restart
Performing sanity check on Samba configuration: OK
smbd not running? (check /var/run/samba/smbd.pid).
nmbd not running? (check /var/run/samba/nmbd.pid).
Removing stale Samba tdb files: ...... done
Starting nmbd.
Starting smbd.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the lines:

```
wins support = yes
guest account = ftp
```

And changing the line

```
interfaces = 192.168.1.254/24 192.168.1.253/24
```

to

```
interfaces = wlan0
```

And then performing:

```
$ /usr/local/etc/rc.d/samba stop
smbd not running? (check /var/run/samba/smbd.pid).
Stopping nmbd.
Waiting for PIDS: 2219.
$ /usr/local/etc/rc.d/samba status
nmbd is not running.
smbd is not running.
$ /usr/local/etc/rc.d/samba start
Removing stale Samba tdb files: ....... done
Starting nmbd.
Starting smbd.
```

Appears to have resolved the issue. I guess there was either a clash with wins support, or the guest account `ftp` didn't exist or some such silly business.